# Java why does Calendar.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET) give 0 during daylight savings time?

Tags: java, dst, java-calendar

I have a Calendar object that corresponds to 2021-07-05T18:00:00.000-04:00 (Eastern Daylight Time). Yet Calendar.get(DST_OFFSET) and Calendar.getTimeZone().getDSTSavings() both give 0. It should be 1 hour. What am I missing or what am I going wrong? All the other methods I play with are returning the expected values.

I am creating the Calendar using setTimeInMillis() and TimeZone using offsets. Is that the reason it is not working? The displayed civil times are always right...

As much as I would like to use the new Java time I am using Java for Android. Last I checked only the most recent versions of Android support the new Java time. They may eventually add support to their older versions.

Comment: That old and outdated API is the reason, use `java.time`...

Comment: Are you *sure* your TZ is EDT? https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/16-javasystemproperties

Comment: Exactly what deHaar said, don't use `Calendar`, it's obsolete. The newer Java Date and Time API available in the `java.time` package does things like these right.

Comment: I am using Java for Android. I think I am stuck with Calendar if I want to support Android versions less than 10 or 11  (I want to support 5 and up).

Comment: Did you check whether [coreLibraryDesugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) will get you back to those versions?

Comment: What is the real problem, if any? EDT is not a time zone, and surely your Android device cannot have its time zone set to EDT?

Comment: @Ole I am using Android to process information obtained elsewhere. My Android may be anywhere but I am getting information about a time stamp from some other location around the world. But all I am getting is the epoch and offset - nothing else. Now I realize that there is no way for the Calendar to know DST rules for that offset. It needs more information - which time zone is that offset in was not supplied.

Comment: From epoch and UTC offset you can calculate the date and time of day. You are right, you cannot from that information know the time zone nor whether it’s in the summer time (daylight saving time) of year or not. There are very many time zones that have offset -04:00 some or all of the year. [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that the input defines an offset from UTC, but not a real time zone with specific rules (like *if DST is applied at all* and if it is, *when will DST be applied*).

`Calendar` is clearly not capable of handling those rules, the class (and probably the entire API) was not designed to be.

That's one of the reasons for `java.time` having been introduced in Java 8.

Here's some example use of `java.time` in a situation like yours:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example String in ISO format
    String dateString = "2021-07-05T18:00:00.000-04:00";
    // define your time zone
    ZoneId americaNewYork = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
    // parse the (zone-less) String and add the time zone
    ZonedDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(dateString)
                                      .atZoneSameInstant(americaNewYork);
    // then get the rules of that zone
    long hours = americaNewYork.getRules()
                               // then get the daylight savings of the datetime
                               .getDaylightSavings(odt.toInstant())
                               // and get the full hours of the dst offset
                               .toHoursPart();
    
    // use a formatter to format the output (nearly) as desired
    System.out.println(odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME)
                        + " has a daylight saving offset of "
                        + hours);
}
```

This prints

```
2021-07-05T18:00:00-04:00[America/New_York] has a daylight saving offset of 1
```

## EDIT:

Your comment made me provide a similar version that uses a `long` as input:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // example String in ISO format
    long input = 1625522400000L;
    // create an Instant from the input
    Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(input);
    // define your time zone
    ZoneId americaNewYork = ZoneId.of("America/New_York");
    // then get the rules of that zone
    long hours = americaNewYork.getRules()
                               // then get the daylight savings of the Instant
                               .getDaylightSavings(instant)
                               // and get the full hours of the dst offset
                               .toHoursPart();
    
    // use a formatter to format the output (nearly) as desired
    System.out.println(ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instant, americaNewYork)
                                    .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME)
                        + " has a daylight saving offset of "
                        + hours);
}
```

The output is just the same as in the above example.

Comment: I think this might be the correct answer. I am not using the Calendar created from the instance, which perhaps knows the time zone. But I am clearing that instance, and creating the calendar from the unix epoch and the TimeZone from the offset. But the Calendar does not know the time zone - just the offset from UTC. I am not sure though.

Comment: @BrianReinhold If your input is a `long` of epoch millis or seconds, you can directly create an `Instant` from it. OK, maybe a `Calendar` could *know* a time zone, but it won't reliably give you the correct offset, especially when daylight saving time comes into play.

Comment: I credit this as the correct answer as it identifies what I was doing wrong. I was not specifying a specific time zone, which you do above, but only providing an offset and the epoch. The offset contains within it the DST shift (given my source)., So of course the Calendar does not know the DST shift. I would have to further specify that this is, for example,  New York time zone (as you do in your example). I did not do that.

Answer (score 0):

in a java bug [tracker](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6615045?focusedCommentId=13327706&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-13327706) you will find your problem.

**During the "fall-back" period, Calendar doesn't support disambiguation and the given local time is interpreted as standard time.
To avoid the unexpected DST to standard time change, call add() to reset the value.**

you can resolve it by replacing set() with

```
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, -cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

Comment: But the OP's date of 2021-07-05 is nowhere near the "fall-back" period, so this issue doesn't apply

Comment: Also, 3 letter TZs are deprecated. If you run your code as `java -Duser.timezone=America/New_York ...` you might find a different result